# QtCreator delete file is not working

Tags: c++, qt-creator

I'm writing a "custom makefile" project using QtCreator and I want to delete a file of my project, so, I select the file in the tree view, press the right click and the "delete" option is disabled and I did not find any way of enable it.

My environment: QtCreator 1.2.1 on SnowLeopard:

[image: Screenshot]

Thanks in advance,

Ernesto

Comment: Did you check the permissions on the file?

Comment: yes, I did; actually my file was created by the same user that is running QtCreator right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the way, I downloaded and installed Qt creator 1.3 beta for Mac OS X and deleting files is working properly.